# How to obtain the decision boundary coordinates of an SVM classification plot

Tags: r, plot, svm

I use SVM for classification and I would like to obtain the coordinates of the boundary to use in another plot. For example

```
library(e1071)      
data(cats, package = "MASS") 
m <- svm(Sex~Bwt+Hwt, data = cats) 
plot(m, cats)
```

[image]

How can I obtain the coordinates of the decision boundary?

Comment: Have a look at the values in `m$coefs` and the post here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/computing-the-decision-boundary-of-a-linear-svm-model